# Separate intersecting time intervals by number of segments (R)

Tags: r, intervals, lubridate

I'm working on a dataset of time intervals. Some intervals overlap. I would like to take the raw interval data, and break it into consecutive intervals, by number of overlaps. In the toy data below, there are 3 intervals. My desired output is a data frame that contains the start and stop of where there's only one ID, then start and stop where ID 1 and ID 2 intersect, then start and stop of where IDs 1-3 intersect, then start and stop of where IDs 1 and 3 intersect, and finally the start and stop of the remainder of ID 1.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Start = structure(c(1690740180, 1690740480, 
1690741380), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Iqaluit"), 
    End = structure(c(1690751520, 1690742140, 1690742280), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Iqaluit")), row.names = 3:5, class = "data.frame")

ggplot(df) + geom_segment(aes(x = Start, xend = End, y = as.factor(ID), yend = as.factor(ID)))
```

Desired output should look like this:

```
  Intervals               Start                 End
         1 2023-07-30 14:03:00 2023-07-30 14:07:59
         2 2023-07-30 14:08:00 2023-07-30 14:22:59
         3 2023-07-30 14:23:00 2023-07-30 14:35:40
         2 2023-07-30 14:35:40 2023-07-30 14:38:00
         1 2023-07-30 14:38:00 2023-07-30 15:06:40
```

I can do this by interpolating the data down to 1 sec and checking for intersections, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a base R solution:

```r
alltimes <- unique(sort(c(df$Start, df$End)))
intervals <- sapply(alltimes[-length(alltimes)],
                    function(tm) df$Start <= tm & tm < df$End)
intervals
#       [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
# [1,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

In `intervals`, each row is a row from the original `df`, each column is a time segment, and the value indicates if the original `df` row was found in that time segment. We can take the sums of each column to create the `Intervals` column, and then the `Start` and `End` columns are merely the pairs of our `alltimes` vector.

```r
data.frame(
  Intervals = colSums(intervals),
  Start = alltimes[-length(alltimes)],
  End = alltimes[-1]
)
#   Intervals               Start                 End
# 1         1 2023-07-30 14:03:00 2023-07-30 14:08:00
# 2         2 2023-07-30 14:08:00 2023-07-30 14:23:00
# 3         3 2023-07-30 14:23:00 2023-07-30 14:35:40
# 4         2 2023-07-30 14:35:40 2023-07-30 14:38:00
# 5         1 2023-07-30 14:38:00 2023-07-30 17:12:00
```

I'm not certain if the new `End` should be the same as the next `Start` or offset by one second, your expected output uses both. Also, I don't know how your last row is `15:06:40` (is not in your raw data), I suspect it's an artifact of your real data and not the sample.

Comment: Amazing. The sneaky base R solutions still surprise me to this day. And yeah, apologies for the couple of artifacts with the toy example.

Comment: Sorry - what are the `intervals` in the answer?

Comment: typo, fixed, sry about that

Comment: `data.frame(...) |> subset(Intervals > 0)`? it looks alright to me, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Gah, never mind. I was using `geom_ribbon` when I should've used `geom_rect`. It's all good :) Sorry~

Comment: I've made the same mistake and was _almost_ there with this one, once I realized it was a plotting issue and not an interval one. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

With [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/), a package for working with intervals:

```r
library(ivs)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

start <- structure(
  c(1690740180, 1690740480, 1690741380),
  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
  tzone = "America/Iqaluit"
)
end <- structure(
  c(1690751520, 1690742140, 1690742280),
  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
  tzone = "America/Iqaluit"
)

x <- iv(start, end)
x
#> <iv<datetime<America/Iqaluit>>[3]>
#> [1] [2023-07-30 14:03:00, 2023-07-30 17:12:00)
#> [2] [2023-07-30 14:08:00, 2023-07-30 14:35:40)
#> [3] [2023-07-30 14:23:00, 2023-07-30 14:38:00)

iv_locate_splits(x) |>
  as_tibble() |>
  mutate(count = lengths(loc))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>                                          key loc       count
#>                                   <iv<dttm>> <list>    <int>
#> 1 [2023-07-30 14:03:00, 2023-07-30 14:08:00) <int [1]>     1
#> 2 [2023-07-30 14:08:00, 2023-07-30 14:23:00) <int [2]>     2
#> 3 [2023-07-30 14:23:00, 2023-07-30 14:35:40) <int [3]>     3
#> 4 [2023-07-30 14:35:40, 2023-07-30 14:38:00) <int [2]>     2
#> 5 [2023-07-30 14:38:00, 2023-07-30 17:12:00) <int [1]>     1
```

If you need to get the start/end back out of the `key` column, use `iv_start()` and `iv_end()`.